# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pvtData')

Tags: next.js, syncfusion

I can't display the data in my grid component (syncfusion). It always throws me an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pvtData')". There is no coming display from my grid components and the error keeps throwing. Is there any mistakes I've made especially in API Routes?

**FRONTEND**

```
 const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';
  const data = new DataManager({
    adaptor: new UrlAdaptor(),
    insertUrl: baseUrl + `/api/subject/insert/${user_id}`,
    updateUrl: baseUrl + `/api/subject/update/${user_id}`,
    deleteUrl: baseUrl + `/api/subject/delete/${user_id}`,
    url: baseUrl + `/api/subject/${user_id},
  });

 <GridComponent
              dataSource={data}
              allowPaging={true}
              pageSettings={{ pageSize: 10 }}
              editSettings={{ allowEditing: true }}
            >
              <ColumnsDirective>
                <ColumnDirective field="Subject" width="200" textAlign="Left" />
                <ColumnDirective field="Name" width="100" />
                <ColumnDirective field="Year" width="100" textAlign="Left" />
                <ColumnDirective field="Section" width="100" textAlign="Left" />
                <ColumnDirective field="Semester" width="100" />
                <ColumnDirective field="Batch" width="100" />
                <ColumnDirective
                  headerText="Delete"
                  width="100"
                  textAlign="Center"
                />
              </ColumnsDirective>
              <Inject services={[Page, Edit]} />
            </GridComponent>
```

**API ROUTES(NEXT):**

```
//  /api/orders/:id

import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

import db from '@/utils/db';
import Subject from '@/models/Subject';
import Class from '@/models/Class';

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  console.log('SESSION: ', session);
  if (!session) {
    return res.status(401).send('Signin required');
  }

  await db.connect();

  const subject = await Subject.find({ teacher_id: req.query.id });

  const dataID = subject.map((sub) => sub.class_id);
  console.log('CLASS ID: ', dataID);

  const classData = await Class.find({ _id: { $in: dataID } });

  const mergedData = subject.map((sub) => {
    const classRecord = classData.find((cls) => cls._id.equals(sub.class_id));
    return {
      ID: sub._id,
      Subject: sub.name,
      Name: classRecord.name,
      Year: classRecord.year,
      Section: classRecord.section,
      Semester: sub.semester,
      Batch: classRecord.batch,
    };
  });

  await db.disconnect();

  res.json(mergedData);
};

export default handler;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that duplicate packages might be installed in your ‘@syncfusion’ folder of ‘node_modules’. Could you please follow the steps provided in the following documentation or use the below steps to overcome the reported behaviour.

1. Delete package.lock.json file from your application.
2. Remove the ‘@syncfusion’ package folder from the node_modules.
3. Use same versions for all components(Grid, Dropdown, etc,) in package.json file.
4. Then install the new packages.

Documentation:  https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/common/how-to/update-npm-package

Regards,

Santhosh I

Comment: point 3 was the fix for me - I had different major versions of Syncfusion packages after an update